Ubuntu Desktop Hiding 20.04
I had developed a PySide6 GUI, i had put that in start application of Ubuntu 20.04, when the system is on the app will launch automatically,But i want it in a way that when the system is on the app should launch automatically and Ubuntu desktop should be hide.
We are developing a device(touch screen) when the device is on the app launches but the new users can drag that software down using their fingers and can see the Ubuntu desktop and use all the features,files.
I don't want to show the  Ubuntu desktop only this GUI should be visible.Can anyone please suggest a solution for this, the users should not be able to see and use Ubuntu

Maybe you should have asked Dr. Google. ;-)  https://superuser.com/questions/503343/gui-apps-without-a-graphical-desktop

Or is it that you want to always run the app in full screen mode?

The app is already running in full screen mode but as it is touchscreen the users can drag the software using fingers and can see the ubuntu desktop, how can i remove the ubuntu gui and show only my custom build gui

Can you please suggest some solutions
